# How do I add a duplicate button action to my tableview when users swipe to the right of the cells

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, cell

I want to implement a duplicate button action when users swipe to the right of the cell in the tableview, I already have implemented a edit and delete button action but cannot find anywhere on how to add a duplicate action.

Comment: Implement [tableView(_:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/2902366-tableview)

Comment: Thank you so much this was what I was looking for.